# will $@ work with vpath

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

```
SRC_DIRS += $(CMM_DIR)
SRC_DIRS += $(ABC_DIR)

VPATH = $(SRC_FILES)

tear_abc123: $(OBJ)/ur23.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(subst tear_,,$@.c) $@.c $@_compiletime.c -o $@
```

In this, $@_compiletime.c (say tear_abc123_compiletime.c) gets generated before $(CC). make throws an error that abc123.c is not found. where abc123.c is present in $(ABC_DIR). Why vpath is could not find the c file.

Comment: 1) The line  `vpath $@.c $(SRC_FILES)` makes no sense, there's no equal symbol, so no assignation. 2) `VPATH` must contain the path to the folders containing the source files, not the path to the sources. 3) Read the [Rules of Makefiles](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/) . 4) What you want is `VPATH = $(SRC_DIRS)` where `SRC_DIRS` holds the different folders containing your sources.

Comment: I have changed and VPATH still fails to find the file. Throws an error abc123.c no such file or directory

Comment: In your edit `VPATH` takes the value of `SRC_FILES` not `SRC_DIRS`. Please read [VPATH documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html). VPATH is the list of places where `make` will look for your source files. If you don't tell `make` where your sources are, it won't find them.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that `VPATH` works only for Prerequisites. And it does not work from the 'command' part of the target.

To make `VPATH` work you should specify list of sources in Prerequisites and reference it in the command using `$^`.

Please see the following example (for file tree as below)

```
.
|-- abc
|   |-- abc123.c
|   |-- tear_abc123.c
|   `-- tear_abc123_compiletime.c
`-- Makefile
```

Makefile contains

```
SRC_DIRS := abc
VPATH := $(SRC_DIRS)

TARGET := tear_abc123

SOURCE_FILES := $(TARGET).c $(TARGET)_compiletime.c $(subst tear_,,$(TARGET).c)

tear_abc123: $(SOURCE_FILES)
        @echo "SOURCE_FILES := $(SOURCE_FILES)"
        @echo "prerequisites = $^"
```

The output will be

```
$ make
SOURCE_FILES := tear_abc123.c tear_abc123_compiletime.c abc123.c
prerequisites = abc/tear_abc123.c abc/tear_abc123_compiletime.c abc/abc123.c
```

As you can see

- the `SOURCE_FILES` really contains only source files names
- the prerequisites is automatically substituted with correct path